# Flalign* environment: Put two equations side by side and separate them with vertical line

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, sidebyside, flalign

I need your help.

What I want is putting two formulas/equations side by side.
They should be clearly separated with a vertical line in the middle.

Here comes the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\stackMath
\newcommand\udash[2][\hrulefill]{\stackunder{#2}{\makebox[0.7em]{#1}}}
\newcommand\mygap{\udash[]{}}
\newcommand{\myq}{\,\,\,}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\[
\langle\tabbedShortunderstack{
  \udash{x}&\mygap&\udash{}\\ i&&}\rangle_k 
  \langle\udash{}\mygap x \mapsto i\mygap\udash{}\rangle_{\mathrm{state}}
\]

\[
\rho_{r}:\langle\tabbedShortunderstack{
    \udash{x}&\myq\curvearrowright&\udash{}\\ i&&}\rangle_k \myq
\langle\udash{}\mygap x \mapsto i\rangle_{\mathrm{state}}
\]
\end{center}

\begin{flalign*} %diese sollen in der Mitte von einem vertikalen Strich getrennt werden
\rho_{r}:\langle\tabbedShortunderstack{
    \udash{x}&\myq\curvearrowright&\udash{}\\ i&&}\rangle_k \myq
\langle\udash{}\mygap x \mapsto i\rangle_{\mathrm{state}}
&\myq\rho_{r}:\langle\tabbedShortunderstack{
    \udash{x}&\myq\curvearrowright&\udash{}\\ i&&}\rangle_k \myq
\langle\udash{}\mygap x \mapsto i\rangle_{\mathrm{state}}
\end{flalign*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw[red] (0.5\textwidth,0.5) -- (0.5\textwidth,1.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I will get following result:

[image]

Two questions: 
First, how can I adjust the lenght of the vertical line?
Second, how can I adjust the distance between formula and line?
It should be clear, what I mean.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tikzmark` for that. This allows you to draw the line *exactly* in the middle, and `calc` allows you to fix the length. The distance can be controlled by just adding `\qquad`, say, between the blocks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\stackMath
\newcommand\udash[2][\hrulefill]{\stackunder{#2}{\makebox[0.7em]{#1}}}
\newcommand\mygap{\udash[]{}}
\newcommand{\myq}{\,\,\,}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\[
\langle\tabbedShortunderstack{
  \udash{x}&\mygap&\udash{}\\ i&&}\rangle_k 
  \langle\udash{}\mygap x \mapsto i\mygap\udash{}\rangle_{\mathrm{state}}
\]

\[
\rho_{r}:\langle\tabbedShortunderstack{
    \udash{x}&\myq\curvearrowright&\udash{}\\ i&&}\rangle_k \myq
\langle\udash{}\mygap x \mapsto i\rangle_{\mathrm{state}}
\]
\end{center}

\begin{flalign*} %diese sollen in der Mitte von einem vertikalen Strich getrennt werden
\rho_{r}:\langle\tabbedShortunderstack{
    \udash{x}&\myq\curvearrowright&\udash{}\\ i&&}\rangle_k \myq
\langle\udash{}\mygap x \mapsto i\rangle_{\mathrm{state}}\tikzmarknode{l}{~}
\qquad\tikzmarknode{r}{~}\myq\rho_{r}:\langle\tabbedShortunderstack{
    \udash{x}&\myq\curvearrowright&\udash{}\\ i&&}\rangle_k \myq
\langle\udash{}\mygap x \mapsto i\rangle_{\mathrm{state}}
\end{flalign*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[red] ($(l.north)!0.5!(r.north)+(0,5mm)$) --
($(l.south)!0.5!(r.south)+(0,-3mm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]